# conditional if and else

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

INPUT:

```
     import java.util.*;

     public class Main{ 
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     int a=33;
     int b=7;
     
     if (a>b)
        {System.out.println("the bigger no. is a = " + a); }

     if (a==b)
        {System.out.println("Both the no. are equal ");}

     else
        {System.out.println("the bigger no. is b = " + b);}


 }

}
```

OUTPUT:

the bigger no. is a = 33
the bigger no. is b = 7

QUESTION: Why are two results are coming, a is bigger than b so why the output is both if and else statements

I tried other scenarios but changing the values of a and b but the output is always the same

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are not using the if else statements correctly. The code that you have written will first check if a>b and since it is it will print out the first output. You then call another if statement in your example it is false so it does not print anything out, however, the else statement is only connected to the second if statement and therefore will also print out the second statement when you were expecting the first. The correct implementation would be

```
import java.util.*;

     public class Main{ 
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     int a=33;
     int b=7;
     
     if (a>b)
        {System.out.println("the bigger no. is a = " + a); }

     else if (a==b)
        {System.out.println("Both the no. are equal ");}

     else
        {System.out.println("the bigger no. is b = " + b);}

 }

}
```

Adding else if will add that chain of "if else" statements so you are not getting unexpected results!